# Gson doesn't serialyse mac adresses

Tags: java, android, gson

I want to save the Mac Adress of a Bluetooth device, so I serialize it with Gson to convert it into a String type but it returns nothing.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Log.d("my device", String.valueOf(myBluetoothDevice));   //93:39:1B:04:00:71
String dev = gson.toJson(myBluetoothDevice, BluetoothDevice.class);
Log.d("my device after", dev);   //{}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What is `BluetoothDevice`?

Comment: You really shouldn't pass 2nd parameter in your call to toJson

Comment: I've added it for ensuring the class type, but even without it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the address of a [BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#getAddress()), call the `getAddress` method:

```
String address = myBluetoothDevice.getAddress();
// address = 00:11:22:AA:BB:CC
```

If you want to convert the String into a JSON representation of the string, which basically just adds quotes, then you can use `gson.toJson()`:

```
String addressInJson = gson.toJson(myBluetoothDevice.getAddress());
// addressInJson = "00:11:22:AA:BB:CC"
```